# Changes to Styles not publishing

Tags: cache, mapbox-studio

When adding a layer to a custom style and symbolizing the layer, the new layer doesn't seem to show up in the published style. We have waited a day to ensure the new tiles have had time to render.

For example, here is a layer in Studio:
[image]
And in a leaflet map:
[image]

Notice that the black dashed line, which is the layer that was added to the style is not sowing up. We've cleared the cache in the browser. Any suggestions on how to proceed?